# Binding not works in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular, i am using Angular5.

I have productlist.js, having data in that file. Binded that data in the my html page, it's not working.

If i have the data in html file [ commented code in sample.html ], then it is working as expected.

**productlist.js**

```
angular.module('myShoppingList')
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {


    $scope.products = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese"];

});
```

**Sample.html**

```
<div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in products">{{x}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have added the productlist.js under the head in sample.html

Comment: btw this is not angular5. this is angularjs syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have few mistakes, you need to add empty dependencies to your module as follows,

```
angular.module('myShoppingList',[])
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('myShoppingList',[])
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.products = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in products">{{x}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, how to change the above code into Angular5.. any links to learn ? Kindly help.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: there is no direct way to change to angular5 instead of rewriting it. You will use ngFor instead of ng-repeat.  look the example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1pahgj?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

When you add into html file, the following order of statement is important as well.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="yourSampleScript.js"> </script>
```

Please take into consideration the abovementioned code snippet.